# WF : AsyncCodeActivity: AsyncCodeActivitygetting terminated automatically if execution time exceeds 30 Minutes

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have created an AsyncCodeActivity to write Data in excel sheet which is being called in a workflow, activity is reading data from table in chunk size of 500.
When row count is less it’s working fine but for large data(e.g.: 100000 rows) which takes time approx. an hour, activity is getting terminated automatically.

Can anyone please let me know the solution how to increase the execution time so that activity can complete execution.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Nirbhay

Comment: What are you using to host workflow?

Comment: Using AppFabric to host the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Activity was getting terminated due to 'OutOfMemoryException', i was using SpreadsheetDocument to read and write the data. I used streamwriter to write the data and it is working fine.